# How to integrate ccavenue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I have merchant_id, access key and working key. I have downloaded integration kit which include

> ccavRequestHandler.php, ccavResponseHandler.php, Crypto.php

How to use those file and all those keys in laravel?

I have created checkout page in that user will enter their own information as well as bank information.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at the Laravel documentation?  Do they have support? If you are looking for tutorials here, you will be disappointed.   Instead, share with this group the code that you have tried and describe the errors or roadblocks in better detail

Comment: Yes sir i have read many doc and tutorial but with no luck.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this package https://github.com/softon/indipay 
This package support ccavenue .

After install this via composer , you have to enter  these in config/indipay.php

```
    'merchantId'  => env('INDIPAY_MERCHANT_ID', ''),
    'accessCode'  => env('INDIPAY_ACCESS_CODE', ''),
    'workingKey' => env('INDIPAY_WORKING_KEY', ''),
```

You can redirect to user to ccavenue website ,

```
 $parameters = [
    'tid' => '1',
    'order_id' =>'123',
    'amount' => '1233',
  ];
  $order = Indipay::prepare($parameters);
  return Indipay::process($order);
```

Comment: I am using same library for laravel 5.8, and php 7.2 but getting error 'Call to undefined function Softon\Indipay\Gateways\mcrypt_module_open()'.

Comment: mcrypt_module_open has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0